# BREP intersections C/C++

Tags: c, computational-geometry

What is the preferred methodology to find the intersection of solids using C code?

For instance. I want to find the intersection of two cylinders. How is this commonly done? Do you simply use planes and tangent vectors to find the contour line?  I realize this can be done with parametric equations, however very rarely do you have access to the questions of surfaces unless you use NURBS and beziers.

Comment: There is no "preferred methodology in C". There are generic algorithms, that you probably know more about than I, and you can implement those in C.

Comment: Parametric representation tends not to be practical as it gets to complex for anything but the simplest shapes. Usually half-edge based graphs are used to represent the topology. You can create various boolean ops on these structures. See this question for something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712855/assigning-surfaces-to-zones-based-on-the-3d-regions-they-enclose/31818277#31818277